# Google Chart Line Chart intermittently displays h-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a Line Chart which is really basic.

I have a h-axis of names and then the % calculation of productivity.

Issue: The h-axis displays only some of the time - I can't find any replicable condition to make it appear or re-appear - it's just random.

It is on a page with about 7-8 other charts which all function perfectly.

Here is my code for the intermittent line chart - Is there anything obvious about this that might be causing problems?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table', 'corechart', 'bar', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {

  ...

  var on_time_chart = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  on_time_chart.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  on_time_chart.addColumn('number', 'On Time %');
  on_time_chart.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
  on_time_chart.addRows([
    ['Ron', 83.3, 83.3],
    ['Ed', 45.5, 45.5],
    ['Gary', 25.0, 25.0],
  ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('on_time_perf_chart'));
  chart.draw(on_time_chart, { width: 500,
                            height: 350,
                            chartArea:{left:50,top:10,width:350,height:150},
                            pointSize: 5,
                            legend: {title: 'On Time%', position: 'bottom', alignment: ''},
                            hAxis: {showTextEvery: 1, slantedTextAngle: 50, slantedText: 1},
                            vAxis: {title: '%'}
                        });
}
```

NOTE: I have removed {showTextEvery: 1, slantedTextAngle: 50} and it appears to work BUT this creates an ugly display.  I can't add any additional config options to hAxis without the labels disappearing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution - I had code in the footer of the page which attempted to add a listener to the page to detect a resize and then issue a drawVisualization call to resize the charts.

Removed this and problem solved.

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawVisualization);
}
else if (document.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', drawVisualization);
}
else {
    window.resize = drawVisualization;
}
```